# Delete a collection of dates in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to delete a CinemaProgramme from database when the timetable List satisfies my requirement. When I tried to delete cinemaProgramme I got the exception that I cannot delete that because of the foreign key in the list.
I heard about the " orphanRemoval option on the OneToMany and OneToOne annotations and XML. Orphan removal will ensure that any object no longer referenced from the relationship is deleted from the database."
But I cannot use it as I have a elementcollection mapping not onetomany etc.

So I tried to delete first the list and then the CinemaProgramme, but when try to execute:

```
String hql1 = "delete CinemaProgramme.timetable as p where p in (:list)";
    Query q1 = session.createQuery(hql1);       
    q1.setParameterList("list", q.list());
    q1.executeUpdate();
```

I get an exception 
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CinemaProgramme.timetable is not mapped. I spent hours on this problem:(

CinemaProgramme class:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "cinema_programme")
    public class CinemaProgramme implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "programme_id")
    private List<Date> timetable;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

    @Column(name = "dubbing")
    private boolean dubbing;
}
```

.......
EDIT
    for:

```
String hql1 = "delete CinemaProgramme as p where p.timetable in (:list)";
Query q1 = session.createQuery(hql1);
            List d = q.list();
            q1.setParameterList("list", d);
System.out.println(d); - displays [2015-02-01 00:00:00.0]
```

i get:
.....

```
7772 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No value specified for parameter 
dContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:101)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Think your query must `String hql1 = "delete CinemaProgramme as p where p.timetable in (:list)";`

Comment: Then I get the exception: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1. But q.list() returns [2015-02-01 00:00:00.0] .....

Comment: Look at my post. I do executeUpdate :). q.list I use for a different query and its result i put to my delete.

Comment: @user2455862 Add the full exception as an update to your question.

Comment: @user2455862 can you put the result of `q.list()`in a variable and then the variable in the parameter?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Did you see my question edit? I put it like:   List d = q.list();
            q1.setParameterList("list", d);

Comment: You should change your code to `List d = q.list(); q1.setParameterList("list", d);` and try again.